# Context package vs done channel to avoid goroutine leak

Tags: go, concurrency

There are two different approaches to clean up a goroutine.

1. Use a kill channel to signal cancellation and a done channel to indicate that goroutine has been terminated.

   ```
   type Worker struct {
     Done chan struct{}
     Kill chan struct{}
     Jobs chan Job
   }

   func (w *Worker) Run() {
     defer func() {
       w.Done <- struct{}{}
     }
     for {
       select {
       case <-w.Kill:
         return
       case j := <-w.Jobs:
         // Do some work
     }
   }

   go w.Run()
   w.Kill <- struct{}{}
   ```
2. Use `context` to cancel

   ```
   type Worker struct {
     Ctx context.Context
     Cancel context.CancelFunc
     Jobs chan Job
   }

   func (w *Worker) Run() {
     for {
       select {
       case <-w.Ctx.Done():
         return
       case j := <-w.Jobs:
         // Do some work
     }
   }

   go w.Run()
   w.Cancel()
   ```

What are the pros/cons of each approach? Which one should I default to?

I understand that if I want to kill a tree of interconnected goroutines, I should go with context approach but let's just say I have a simple worker that doesn't start other goroutines internally.

Comment: The context method is simpler, composable, allows for cancel or timeout, and standard. Why would you _not_ use it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> [Go 1.7 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7)
>
> [Context](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#context)
>
> Go 1.7 moves the golang.org/x/net/context package into the standard
>   library as context. This allows the use of contexts for cancelation,
>   timeouts, and passing request-scoped data in other standard library
>   packages, including net, net/http, and os/exec, as noted below.
>
> For more information about contexts, see the [package
>   documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) and the Go blog post “[Go Concurrent Patterns:
>   Context](https://blog.golang.org/context).”

---

There were problems. The context package was introduced to solve them.

Now that you have read all of the relevant documentation, What is your question?

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't sure what is the latest canonical approach to goroutine cancellation because I think I saw a misleading article and thought some people are arguing for the case that context isn't for cancellation. With your answer, I think it further confirms that context should be the default go-to method for cancellation.