# How to interrupt sending on a channel

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a component that queries a database for events and notifies the user if a new event is available via a channel. It basically looks like this:

```
type struct Watcher {
  events chan Event
}

func (w *Watcher) Watch() <- chan Event {
 w.fetch()
 return w.events
}

func (w *Watcher) Stop() {
 // ???
}

func (w *Watcher) fetch() {
 //...
  for {
    //...
    e := fetchEvent()
    w.events <- e
    time.sleep(10)
    //...
  }
}
```

The client side then looks like this:

```golang
events := NewWatcher().Events()
e := <- events
//...
```

My question is how can I correctly implement the `Stop()` method?
Especially, how can I interrupt the sender if it is currently waiting for being able to send an event to the channel I know that closing the channel from the receiver side is no option. What's the best practice on this type of issue?

Comment: A send will not block if you put it in a `select`. Then you just need to notify the goroutine to shut down or abort instead of try to send in some manner.

Comment: @Moonlit: if you are in doubt now what to do because of our "stop channel" vs "context" debate, sorry about that. Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335907/context-package-vs-done-channel-to-avoid-goroutine-leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can stop by context. This is better because with channels for stopping it could block if for some reason the other side is already stopped or blocked by something else, etc.

```golang
type Watcher struct {
    events chan Event
    cancel context.CancelFunc
}

func (w *Watcher) Watch() <-chan Event {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    w.cancel = cancel
    go w.fetch(ctx)
    return w.events
}

func (w *Watcher) Stop() {
    w.cancel()
}

func (w *Watcher) fetch(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        e := fetchEvent()
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case w.events <- e:
        }
    }
}
```

This example creates a `Context` in the `Watch` function (before fetching gets started) and registers the `cancel` function in the Watcher. The `ctx` is then passed on to `fetch` which checks for `ctx.Done` on every iteration. If the context is `Done`, it will stop fetching.

---

You might want to initialize the `cancel` function to be an empty function so it is never `nil` and `Stop` can be called without a `panic` even if the `Watcher` was never started.

```golang
func NewWatcher() *Watcher {
    return &Watcher{
        // ...
        cancel: func() {},
    }
}
```

---

If you additionally want to pass in a context from the outside, you can rewrite your `Watch` function to:

```golang
func (w *Watcher) Watch(ctx context.Context) <-chan Event {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    w.cancel = cancel
    w.fetch(ctx)
    return w.events
}
```

Now the `Watcher` will stop to `fetch` if the `Stop` function is called or the outside `ctx` is cancelled (e.g. if your application shuts down).

---

If the `Watcher.events` channel is not used anywhere else, you can create it in the `Watch` function and pass it to `fetch` as well as return it. That way the `Watch` function can also be called multiple times and they will have separate channels, and not multiple readers reading from the same channel.

If you do this, you probably also want to have a way to cancel them individually, so you could return the `cancel` function from the `Watch` function and remove it from the `Watcher` struct. Also `Stop` is now obsolete.

```golang
func (w *Watcher) Watch() (<-chan Event, context.CancelFunc) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    
    // with small buffer for channel to smooth sending/receiving
    ch := make(chan Event, 5)
    
    go w.fetch(ctx, cancel, ch)
    return ch, cancel
}

func (w *Watcher) fetch(ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc, ch chan<- Event) {
    // make sure the context is cancelled always if `fetch` stops to avoid goroutine leak.
    defer cancel()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // now you can close it without problems
            close(ch)
            return
        case ch <- fetchEvent():
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd have a `Stop` function with an internal `done` channel just in case, and allow for the user to pass in a context to the constructor. The watcher can than be made to gracefully terminate either when the application context is cancelled, or the caller no longer needs  to use this specific caller

Comment: If you want an application context passed in, put it in the `Watch(ctx context.Context)` function and replace `context.Background()` with the `ctx`. Channels are not a good way to stop something.

Comment: Channels are used _all the time_ to stop something. The `context.Context` uses channels for that exact reason: `ctx.Done()` returns `<- chan struct{}`, for example

Comment: They shouldn't.  Your solution will panic if `Stop` is called twice. Also you can easily block forever.

Comment: The fact that context shouldn't use a channel is something you ought to take up with the people over at google who develop the language. For now, it's standard practice, widely used, and examples of using the closing of a channel to communicate the end of something running is found in standard lib, 3rd party code, The Go programming language book, and other resources.

Comment: Yes, because there was not context.Context at the time it was written or it was written by people who still find those old examples and do the same. Doesn't mean it is good practice.

Comment: Mate, I've got better things to do than argue about the why's and what if's of language design. There's plenty of real-life cases where I'm using context + channels for different reasons (e.g. where a component consuming data needs to stay registered, but temporarily skipped). Sure, I could use a wrapped context and keep a reference to 2 context's and 2 cfunc's around, but really, a channel is fine if you know what you're doing, easier to implement/handle. There's more than one way to do it

Comment: Well, then why don't you make your example 100% secure concerning `panics` and `blocking` and then we can see if it as simple as you claim. Your solution has problems with edge cases. It might work for you in your use cases, but it is not good enough for someone asking on Stackoverflow to use as a pattern. I had lots of stop channels before `context.Context` got added to the stdlib and now that I got rid of all of them I definitely have cleaner, shorter and better code.

Comment: @TehSphinX Thanks for your proposal. Shouldn't the third line of the `Watch(ctx)` method look like this: `go w.fetch(ctx)` in order to let that happen in the background?

Comment: @Moonlit: That is correct. Copy/Pasted from your example. I will correct it.

Comment: Now that I'm taking a closer look at that part, you might also want to create the event channel in the `Watch` function and pass it on to the `fetch` function. That depends a bit on what else you are doing with it.

Comment: @TehSphinX Thanks, after calling `Stop()`, the events channel will still be opened right?

Comment: Yes. You do not need to close it, but if you want you can close it in the `select` before returning. Note that after closing you would have to create a new one if you want to call `Watch` again on the same instance after closing. And then it becomes tricky as you will run into data races with the events field on the Watcher. Will add that to my answer.

Comment: @TehSphinX I am still a bit confused about the channel blocking behavior. Isn't the last line above (`ch <- fetchEvent()`) blocking forever if there is no receiver consuming the message, even if somebody called the cancelFunc ?

Comment: Right. It needs to be pulled into the select. Changed it above so it still cancels if the data channel is blocking. You might want to put a small buffer into the data channel sending/reading can run smoother.

Comment: @TehSphinX thx, can you explain how this fixes the problem? if there is no consumer and we are currently in the second case statement, does it block forever? Or is there some magic involved which prevents executing the case statement? Or is this exactly why you propose introducing a buffer?

Comment: @Moonlit: A `select` statement executes the case that is ready to be executed. If the second one blocks, the first one will be executed if it is ready (ctx cancelled in this case). So it will block until the context gets cancelled, then execute the first one. The buffer will only help until it is full, then it would also block if no one reads from it. You can read up on the behaviour of select e.g. here: https://yourbasic.org/golang/select-explained/

Comment: @TheSphinX how does the `fetchEvents` method need to behave in case no event could be fetched? Does it need to return nil? In this case nil would be sent all the time down the channel preventing the execution of all other cases. At least that's how it is behaving right now

Comment: Not sure what your current code is. It shouldn't prevent other cases forever. If multiple cases are ready, one is selected at random. It can happen that a few events get processed after cancellation. You can run it here: https://play.golang.org/p/WGHS6uOd5gv (more next comment on how to prevent that). Note, that I added an err to the getEvent function. Better return an error than just nil if the function cannot fetch an event.

Comment: Here I added a double select that definitely stops immediately if ctx is cancelled: https://play.golang.org/p/xq1WWLdVR1Q. Does any of this answer your question?

Comment: @TheSphincX Yes, thanks I slowly starting to feel comfortable with go channels :)

Comment: Maybe it is worth an upvote and to be marked as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make some assumptions: `Watcher` is going to be a type you're planning to pass around, or at least, you're happy having its functionality be hidden behind a clean interface. Though perhaps not immediately a concern, you want such a component to be safe for concurrent use.

```
type Watcher struct {
    ch   chan Event
    done chan struct{}
}

// New now starts fetching, leave out go w.fetch(ctx) if you don't want this to happen
func New(ctx context.Context) *Watcher {
    w := &Watcher{
        ch:   make(chan Event, 10), // some buffer if needed
        done: make(chan struct{}),  // no buffer needed
    }
    go w.fetch(ctx)
    return w
}

// If you only want to start fetching events when this is called, then uncomment the first line, and allow for context to be passed
func (w *Watcher) Watch() <-chan Event {
    // go w.fetch(ctx)
    return w.ch
}

func (w *Watcher) fetch(ctx context.Context) {
    // this runs in a routine
    // if we stop fetching, close channels
    defer func() {
        if w.done != nil {
            close(w.done)
        }
        w.done = nil
        close(w.ch)
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return // outside context was cancelled
        case <-w.done:
            w.done = nil // prevent second close on done channel
            return // Stop was called
        default:
            w.ch <- fetchEvent() // will block until channel buffer is available
        }
    }
}

func (w *Watcher) Stop() {
    if w.done == nil { // field is set to nil once fetch routine returns
        return
    }
    close(w.done) // rest is handled in fetch routine
}
```

That's pretty much it. I will say, though, that your use of a 10 second sleep until you fetch the next event is better handled using a ticker in the main `fetch` routine:

```
func (w *Watcher) fetch(ctx context.Context) {
    tick := time.NewTicker(10)
    // this runs in a routine
    // if we stop fetching, close channels
    defer func() {
        tick.Stop()
        if w.done != nil {
            close(w.done)
        }
        w.done = nil
        close(w.ch)
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return // outside context was cancelled
        case <-w.done:
            w.done = nil
            return // Stop was called
        case <-tick.C: // every 10 seconds, we'll fetch an event
            w.ch <- fetchEvent()
        }
    }
}
```

Using this type is pretty straightforward:

```
ctx, cfunc := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
watcher := NewWatcher(ctx)
go func() {
    for e := range watcher.Watch() {
        // do something with the data
    }
}()
time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
// either:
watcher.Stop()
// or simply:
cfunc()
```

Comment: This code changes the behaviour as it starts fetching in `NewWatcher`, not in `Watch`.

Comment: Easiest fix in the world, but OK, I'll add it to be explicit

Comment: This will `panic` if you call `Stop` function twice. Not a good idea!

Comment: @TehSphinX: I know, it's also not safe for concurrent use in that calling `Stop` while cancelling the context can result in concurrent access/close calls on the `done` channel, There's a lot more that needs doing to make this code ready to use in an _actual_ real-world application, but that's what edits are for

Comment: Exactly. And that is why you should NOT use stop channels any more. Not since we have context.Context. The context solution is simple in contrast and cannot block, panic or anything else. You can google for it and find a lot of blog posts or stackoverflow answers telling you the same.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanx for the hint of using a ticker instead of `time.sleep`. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Add another channel to your `Watcher`, like `doneChan`, and listen to this channel using `select` in your publisher ( aka sender ) like this:

```
// sender part
events, doneChan := NewWatcher()

select {
case done := <-doneChan:
    // cleanup and return
case events<- message:
}
```

Now you can implement your `Stop()` like this:

```
func (w *Watcher) Stop() {
    w.doneChan<- true
}
```

Your new struct be like:

```
type struct Watcher {
    events   chan Event
    doneChan chan bool
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand why you wrote your answer from the senders perspective as in my example the client code is the one which wants to create a new `Watcher` instance via `NewWatcher()`

Comment: It's better to have `doneChan`be of type `chan struct{}` (an empty struct is 0 bytes, as per spec), and instead of writing a single value to the channel (which only works if you have a single consumer), you're better of closing the channel (`Stop()` effectively is `close(w.doneChan)`).